# Solve the integral $- \int \frac{1}{\cos x} \frac{1}{1-\sin^2x}dx$

Tags: integration

How to solve the following integral?

$$- \int \frac{1}{\cos x} \frac{1}{1-\sin^2x}dx$$

I tried a u substitution with $u=1-\sin^2x$ and $du=-2\cos x$ so $\frac{du}{2}=-\cos x$ so then I get

$$\int \frac{1}{\frac{du}{2}} \frac{1}{u}$$
$$\int \frac{2}{du} \frac{1}{u}$$
and then the $du$ is in the denominator...

Comment: You _can't_ have a '$du$' in the denominator - you've misunderstood your substitution.  $du=-2\cos x\ dx$, and that last part is essential.

Comment: Also, your $du$ is actually incorrect - if $u=1-\sin^2x$ then $du=-2\sin x\cos x\ dx$ (applying the chain rule to $\sin^2x = (\sin(x))^2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\cos x~(1-\sin^2x)}~=~\int\frac{dx}{\cos^3x}~=~\int\frac{\cos x}{\cos^4x}~dx~=~\int\frac{d\big(\sin x\big)}{\big(1-\sin^2x\big)^2}$

Can you take it from here ? :-$)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\int \frac{1}{\cos x} \frac{1}{1-\sin^2x}\,{\rm d}x = \int \frac{1}{\cos x}\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\,{\rm d}x = \int \sec^3x\,{\rm d}x = \int (1+\tan^2x)\sec x\,{\rm d}x$$

Comment: Ok I am looking at this but still not sure how to proceed, there's no obvious substitution that's jumping out to me

Comment: Try $u = \tan x$. So ${\rm d}u = \sec^2 x \,{\rm d}x$ and $\sec x = \sqrt{1+u^2}$.

Comment: @MathMajor You can find $\int\sec^{3}x dx$ using integration by parts, with $u=\sec x$ and $dv=\sec^{2}x dx$.  (Then use $\tan^{2}x=\sec^{2}x-1$ to solve for the integral.)